# changing value of element with a button

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to disable/enable an input line by clicking a button

I can manually enter the word "closed" in an input line and it works fine, but I can not get the "closed" to get entered with a button

```js
       var obj = document.getElementById("state");    
       obj.onchange = function(status){
         if(this.value=="closed"){
            document.getElementById("test").disabled = 'disabled';

         }else{
            document.getElementById("test").disabled = '';
         }
       }
```

```html
    <button id="state" name="state" type="submit" value="open">open</button>
    <button id="state" name="state" type="submit" value="closed">closed</button> 
    <input id="test"/>
```

The input id=state line works fine, but nothing happens when I click the buttons

Comment: you have one more than 1 element with the same Id (which is id= "state"). You should avoid that conflict at all.

Comment: There are two buttons having the same ID's. Note that the ID attribute of html element is unique and must not be duplicated hence will give uncertain result.

Comment: Also if you put these in a form, the page will reload without preventDefault

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a few things to consider :

- You can’t use multiple times the same `ID` (state)
- A button won’t react to a `onChange`, but a `onClick`
- You can directly use the `onClick` HTML attribute

```js
function disableInput(disabled){
  document.getElementById("test").disabled = disabled
}
```

```html
<button onClick="disableInput(false)">open</button>
<button onClick="disableInput(true)">closed</button>

<input id="test" />
```

Comment: Yes you can but it is not recommended. What new does this answer bring to the question?

Comment: It brings joy, flowers, and a simple solution that works, to a OP that is not yet at a level where he want to hear about unobtrusive javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want a toggle?

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  document.getElementById("state").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // not really needed on type="button"
    var closed = this.value == "closed";
    this.value = this.innerText = closed ? "open" : "closed";
    document.getElementById("test").disabled = closed;
  })
})
```

```html
<button id="state" name="state" type="button" value="open">open</button>
<input id="test" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this,

```js
var buttonClick = function(status) {
  if (status == "closed") {
    document.getElementById("test").disabled = true;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("test").disabled = false;
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="openState" name="OpenState" type="submit" value="open" onclick="buttonClick(value)">open</button>
<button id="closedState" name="ClosedState" type="submit" value="closed" onclick="buttonClick(value)">closed</button>

<input id="test" />
```

Comment: It amazes me that that actually works. So the inline handler actually sends the value in your construct!!!